# How to disable ICMP timestamp on AIX - not using firewall

Tags: aix, icmp

On AIX 6/7 how can we disable this function? I cannot see any in "man no".

Installing firewall just because of this is not really an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ICMP timestamp requests and replies can be blocked using ip filters.

Once the filesets are installed, you will need to create configuration file for ipf

```
# vi /etc/ipf.conf
```

add the following as the contents:

```
# Block ICMP timestamp requests and replies
block in log proto icmp from any to any icmp-type 13 
block in log proto icmp from any to any icmp-type 14
```

Load the IP filter kernel extension

```
# /usr/lib/methods/cfg_ipf -l
```

Load the IP filter rules

```
# ipf -f /etc/ipf.conf
```

Confirm the rules were loaded

```
# ipfstat -i
```

> block in log proto icmp from any to any icmp-type timest
>
> block in log proto icmp from any to any icmp-type timestrep

Start the IP filter logging daemon, if desired

```
# /usr/sbin/ipmon -s -D
```

To load the IP filter kernel extension and rules at boot, you can create a script to be called from the inittab

```
# vi /etc/rc.ipf
```

with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#
# Script to load ip filter kernel extension,
# filter rules, and logging
#

# Load IPFilter into kernel
/usr/lib/methods/cfg_ipf -l

# Load ipmon and log to syslog
/usr/sbin/ipmon -s -D

# Load IP filter rules
/usr/sbin/ipf -Fa -f /etc/ipf.conf
```

Make the script executable

```
# chmod 755 /etc/rc.ipf
```

Then add an entry to the inittab to execute the script at run level 2

```
# mkitab "rcipf:2:once:/etc/rc.ipf > /dev/console 2>&1 # Load IP Filter"
```

ipmon will send messages to syslog using the local0 facility. If you wish to log those messages, you can configure syslog to do so.

```
# vi /etc/syslog.conf
```

Add the following line as the contents:

```
local0.debug     /var/adm/local0.log
```

Then run the commands:

```
# touch /var/adm/local0.log
# refresh -s syslogd
```

Source: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1012909

Also, regardless of what you use, you should always have at least the basic firewall set up.

Comment: Including the steps from the link would make this a good answer...

Comment: @JeffSchaller done

Comment: And this would only touch icmp timestamp regarding the firewall, nothing else? there is no other way? :) Big Thanks!

Comment: pepite yes it should only affect your icmp packets

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to disable this using the network tunable.

```
no -p -o icmptimestamp=0
```

You can check what the value is set to with:

```
no -L icmptimestamp
```

Should looks something like this

```
root> no -L icmptimestamp
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NAME                      CUR    DEF    BOOT   MIN    MAX    UNIT           TYPE
     DEPENDENCIES
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
icmptimestamp             0      1      0      0      1      boolean           D
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Since this tunable is of type D, it is dynamic and takes effect immediately.  No reboot is required.

```
Parameter types:
    S = Static: cannot be changed
    D = Dynamic: can be freely changed
    B = Bosboot: can only be changed using bosboot and reboot
    R = Reboot: can only be changed during reboot
    C = Connect: changes are only effective for future socket connections
    M = Mount: changes are only effective for future mountings
    I = Incremental: can only be incremented
```

On some machines I have seen the error that icmptimestamp is Invalid

```
    root> no -L icmptimestamp
no: 1485-110 Invalid tunable name icmptimestamp
```

If this is the case you can add it to /etc/tunables/nextboot and it will disable it after your next reboot

```
icmptimestamp = "0"
```